# How delete other files on mac? because I Don't have enough space to upgrade my OS

Tags: macos

I need to upgrade my os but i dont have enough space , i want to delete some file from other folder but i cannot find it, can some one help me out on how to find this folder

[image]

Comment: If you cannot access them and you have an external drive, you could just move some of the documents to the external drive temporarilly until the update is finished and them move them back after.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer usage. [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) is a better place to ask about macOS, and there are already [questions there about tracking down "Other" space](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space) (hint: it's not a single folder, just a catchall category, so you need other tools to find out where most of the space usage actually is).

Comment: i will try it thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on AskDifferent website.

Comment: 1) use OmniDiskSweeper - it's free and effective 2) move this question to AskDifferent